# image not displaying on Web page in Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf template engine and place the files like that.
but images do not display on Web page. how can i fix it?
[place files like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWrER.png)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdHa7.png)

```
<span class="Google">
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/google.png">
    </a>
</span>

<span class="kakao">
    <a href="">
        <img src="img/kakao.png">
    </a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may change the image reference to:

```
<img th:src="@{/img/google.png}">
```

It will add context-relative url to the image's uri.

Here is the [document](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html).

Answer (score 1):

put / at the start of url and make sure .png should be present at /resource/static/img/ directory

try this

```
<span class="kakao">
    <a href="">
        <img src="/img/kakao.png">
    </a>
</span>
```